# How to force text and figures to be on the same page when minipage, samepage, nopagebreak do not work

Tags: floats, page-breaking, minipage

I'm trying to get four figures (centered on a page in a 2x2 grid) to show up on the same page as the section heading ("Appendix").

The following puts the word "Appendix" on one page (all by itself) and then the four figures on their own page.

I've messed with `\nopagebreak`, `\begin{samepage}...\end{samepage}`, `\begin{minipage}...\end{minipage}` with no luck.

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{sid}
\vfill\eject
\appendix
\label{sec:ads}
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\subfigure[]{
  \includegraphics[height=150pt]{./figs/jjj.png}
  \label{fig:jjj}
} \quad
\subfigure[]{
  \includegraphics[height=150pt]{./figs/xxx.png}
  \label{fig:xxx}
} \quad
\subfigure[]{
  \includegraphics[height=150pt]{./figs/nnn.png}
  \label{fig:nnn}
} \quad
\subfigure[]{
  \includegraphics[height=150pt]{./figs/aaaa.png}
  \label{fig:aaa}
} \quad
\caption{blah  }
\label{fig:aaaa}
\end{figure*}
```

The `\vfill\eject` business is to get the word "Appendix" to appear at the top of a new page, not right after the bibliography. BTW, `\appendix` has this entry in the `cls` file:

```
 \def\appendix{\par
 \section*{APPENDIX}
 \setcounter{section}{0}
 \setcounter{subsection}{0}
 \def\thesection{\Alph{section}} }
```

Comment: Rather than `\vfill\eject`, just use `\newpage`. LaTeX will only put a `figure*` at the top of a page. Try the `H` option as Ian suggested. In general, if you tell a figure to float, it will float. If you don't want that, try any of the solutions you can find by searching this site for floating graphics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, in this case, you don't want your figures to float, so the natural approach would be not to use float environments. You can use `minipage`s to properly align your subfigures, and using the `\captionof` command provided by the [caption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) and `subcaption` packages you can give a caption to your subfigures and to your figure, allowing corresponding labels for cross-references. Here's a little example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\appendix
\chapter{Test Appendix}\label{sec:ads}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=150pt]{./figs/jjj.png}
  \captionof{subfigure}{First subfigure.}
  \label{fig:jjj}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=150pt]{./figs/xxx.png}
  \captionof{subfigure}{Second subfigure.}
  \label{fig:xxx}
\end{minipage}\\
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=150pt]{./figs/nnn.png}
  \captionof{subfigure}{Third subfigure.}
  \label{fig:nnn}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=150pt]{./figs/aaaa.png}
  \captionof{subfigure}{Fourth subfigure.}
  \label{fig:aaa}
\end{minipage}
\captionof{figure}{A figure with four subfigures.}
\label{fig:aaaa}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

I added the `demo` option to the `graphicx` package in order to make my example compilable for everyone; do *not* use that option in your actual code.

As a side note, you seem to be using the `subfigure` package; this package is obsolete and shouldn't be used anymore; you can use the `subcaption` package instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think this has something to do with the fact that you are using `figure*`. Normally
you can use the `[H]` option provided by the [float](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/float) package.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
...
\end{figure}
```

will force the figure to exactly where it appears in the input file. However, starred figures can only appear at the top of a page, or on their own page.